# Java thread running on which processor?

Tags: java, multithreading, processor

Is there a way to find out which processor (either on a single system or mutliple systems) your thread is running on, using Java native threads? If not, is there any library which could help?

Comment: Thanks people for all your answers. I understand that what I should be more concerned about is CPU usage of the threads. This was just a question I asked out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 2):

The JVM's thread scheduler is JVM-specific, so there is no 'universal' solution. As far as I know there is nothing available out-of-the-box, but perhaps using:

- the Sun JVM;
- Solaris - or Mac, as  *Tom Hawtin - tackline* points out;
- [DTrace](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/dtrace.html).

you might have some luck:

- trace a `thread-start` probe, which has as `args[3]` the "The native/OS thread ID. This is the ID assigned by the host operating system "
- map the native/OS thread ID to a CPU, using Solaris-specific utilities.

Comment: dtrace is also available on Mac OS X (pity the JRE will be behind the times).

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of such a call, and I highly doubt there is one, as it's not really necessary, and would require extra platform-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the standard JDK does not support it (at least up to JDK 6). If that's what you really need, you'll probably need to execute some native calls using JNI. A nice example could be found [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-11/01-qa-1108-cpu.html) (while it's not exactly what you need, I believe it's a good start).

There is a lot of other information you can get from the JDK, by the way, using the ThreadMXBean class (like CPU usage per thread), and maybe you can find what you're looking for [there](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html).

Answer (score 0):

The OS will schedule threads on different processors at different times. So even if you get a snapshot of where each thread is running at any given moment, it could be out of date within milli-seconds.

What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Perhaps to can do what you want without having to know this.