# What is the Thread.State of a thread after Thread.yield()?

Tags: java, concurrency

What is the `Thread.State` of a thread after `Thread.yield()` ? Is it a `Thread.State.WAITING`? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No,  the thread will still be in the [`RUNNABLE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#RUNNABLE) state.  Note that `RUNNABLE` signifies that a thread is available to be run and may be either currently running or waiting its turn.  [`Thread.STATE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) does not distinguish between a thread that is currently executing and a thread that is ready to run, they are both `RUNNABLE`.

A thread will only enter the [`WAITING`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING) state when either `wait()`, `join()` or `LockSupport.park()` has been called.

By calling [`Thread.yield()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) method the currently running thread is voluntarily giving up its slice of CPU time.  This thread then goes from running back into a ready state.

Comment: @krock: so it's Runnable though it gives the thread-scheduler an apportunity to activate a different thread?

Comment: @Max, yes `yield()` is a notification to the system that it should give other threads a chance to run.  If there is nothing else to do, the thread could simply continue executing.

Comment: RUNNABLE, not RUNNING. It could run if the schedule gives it a slice. In contrast a thread calling join() can not run (ie is not runnable) at this time.

Comment: @EricSchaefer & @krock: Thanks for pointing. So there is Thread.State.RUNNABLE status with substates like "running/non-running"... And a separate thing Thread.State.WAITING (for join). Ok. One more question, guys. **What is the programmatic way to know if Thread.State.RUNNABLE thread is actually in wait or is executing?**

Comment: Check this [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974277). I don't think it is really possible (without a ton of messing around), in a single CPU system your code running at the time is in the one and only executing thread.

Comment: You want to know if the thread is actually executing right now? I don't think you can figure this out from inside the jvm. You would also have to define what "now" actually means.

Comment: @krock & @eric. Thanks for giving ideas to explore further :)

Comment: @EricSchaefer: what does it mean when say that  _Thread leaves the CPU_. Does it means, thread leaves the runnable state.

Comment: @Nizan: What are you refering to?

Comment: @EricSchaefer: Referring to state of thread. When said that _wait()_ and _sleep()_ is called _Thread leaves the CPU._ Does it means, thread leaves the runnable state i.e. not eligible to run. Please spell the name correctly it's _Nizam_ so that I can be notified.

Comment: @Nizam I don't know. My comment on this thread is about 8 years old and I have not been doing a lot of Java since then. Your question also seems to be a general one and not really related to this thread. Turn this into a real SO question and a lot of people will be able to answer it.