# What defines an "active" thread?

Tags: java, concurrency

In Java concurrency, what makes a thread "*active*"? Just the fact that it's not idling? Is a "waiting" or "suspended" thread still considered, technically, active?

Comment: What is the context where "active" appears? It's too general a term to provide a hard definition with so little information.

Comment: "It is generally acceptable to have 4 - 20 active threads per core".

Comment: An active `java` thread is a thread that is *eligible* to be the currently running thread of execution. It is a thread that has left the "new" state and has attained (or re-attained) the "runnable" state. Active threads take up residency in the runnable thread pool. It is a common mistake for the context sensitive term *active* to be taken as "the runnable thread that is currently running".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can tell the term 'active' seems to be used a lot but not ever defined.  The `ThreadGroup.enumerate()` method is documented to:

> Copies into the specified array every active thread in this thread
>   group and its subgroups.

and from [looking at the source for this](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.java.html#411), it is checking the [`Thread.isAlive()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive%28%29) method and adding those to the enumerable.  From this I deduce that the terms 'active' and 'alive' are interchangeable and 'alive' is defined as:

> A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at java.lang.Thread.State

In other non Java systems, active equates to "RUNNABLE". A Task/Process/Thread is active if it is able to actively run code. It is suspended if it is not (blocking, etc.)

As Stephen C said, active is being used more as English rather then Java here.

Answer (score 1):

In this context I take "active" to mean that they are executing code. Inactive threads--those that are blocked on I/O calls or awaiting locks--consume only memory resources without affecting the CPU (or only marginally).

However, it really depends on what your threads are doing. If each thread is iterating over numbers to calculate primes, they are fully CPU-bound, and you should really only have one per core to maximize throughput. If they are making HTTP requests or performing file I/O, you can afford to have quite a few per core.

In the end, a blanket statement covering all threads in general without regard for what they are doing is pretty worthless.

I highly recommend the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) for a high-quality treatment of the topic of concurrent Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

The word "active" is being used in normal English sense here.

A normal English meaning of the word active is "doing something".  So an intuitive meaning of "active" for threads is that they are actually executing or are ready to execute.

In the context of this quote:

> *"It is generally acceptable to have 4 - 20 active threads per core"*

the word "active" is used consistently with this, though I'd quibble with the numbers.  (20 is rather too high, IMO).

However, I'd argue that this is an intentionally vague statement.  The give aways are the use of the weasel phrase "it is generally accepted" (rather than citing any specific sources) and the wide range ("4 - 20").  Thus, you could make the case that the word "active" is another example of intentional vagueness.

IMO, the author of the quote is trying to make the general point that "too many threads is bad" ... without being precise about what "too many" is.  Extracting more precise guidance by tying down what he means by "active" is pointless.  (And to be clear, it is **not possible** to say how many "too many" is ... in general.)

Answer (score 0):

> "It is generally acceptable to have 4 - 20 active threads per core". – Adam Tannon

In this sense I think the word means "ready to run" rather than "alive" or any of the other possible meanings.  It makes sense to have no more than a handful of threads on the ready queue, because you're not getting any value for the waiting threads, and you contribute to scheduling and context switch overhead.  On the other hand, if you have fewer ready-to-run threads than cores, you aren't making use of the available resource.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275210/what-is-the-thread-state-of-a-thread-after-thread-yield