# Is there any way to find the number of threads running in Java with the task manager?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, suppose if I start 1000 threads with a loop as below, is there any way I can monitor the number of threads actually running and the CPU resources that the threads consume with task manager?

```
for(int j=0; j<=1000; j++)
{
    MyThread mt = new MyThread ();
    mt.start ();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `VisualVM` or `JConsole` or any other monitoring tool

Comment: Thanks but in task manager process i can see the number of threads running against javaw. Is that don't have anything to deal with?

Comment: @assylias:I was not aware of this option.Good to know!

Comment: @Deepak:You will get more useful information by using `VisualVM` that is already shipped with your JDK

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Windows task manager then yes, you can customize the columns shown in the process tab:

```
Menu View > Select Columns > Threads
```

**EDIT**

A quick test shows that creating an additional thread does increment that counter by one - and when that thread terminates, the counter decrements.

But it starts with more than one thread, because it probably includes the various JVM threads too (it starts with 19 threads). Note that jconsole shows 10 threads on a mono-thread program too.

If you use visual VM, you can see the split between daemon and non daemon threads (all JVM threads are daemon).

Test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        new Thread(r).start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: ya i know that, but is that it literally shows the thread active if i run the above code?

Comment: Is the number of operating system threads used by JVM process always equal to the number of Java threads?

Comment: @assylias:I think it includes the `JVM` daemon threads as well, since `JVM` starts a single process and Windows are only aware of that process

Comment: @Cratylus Yes - I pointed that out in my edit. There seems to be about 10 more threads than what jconsole shows (and jconsole already shows more threads than just what you actually start).

Answer (score 1):

In code you can use [Thread.activeCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#activeCount%28%29) method

Comment: Incorrect.  An "active" thread is simply a thread for which `Thread.isAlive()` returns `true`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360030/what-defines-an-active-thread.  There is no guarantee that an "active" thread is actually running, or even runnable.

Comment: So, it depends on `MyThread` realization - if it can be suspended, then `activeCount()` is incorrect, in another situation you can use it, yes?

Comment: @StephenC:From Javadoc: `A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died`.So it is either `Running` or `Runnable` but the `has not yet died part` includes GC or something?

Comment: @Cratylust - I know that.  But that does not mean that an "alive" is actually running.  It could be waiting on a lock or waiting for IO.  (Waiting threads are not runnable).  If could also be ready to run ... but not running because the OS thread scheduler hasn't scheduled it.  The OP wants to know the "the number of threads *actually running*" not the number of live threads.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/) is a  better tool for this purpose.  You'll get threads and a lot more information if you download and install all the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  managed bean for this perpers (MXBean).  For example ThreadMXBean.

To get MXBean just call

```
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean()
```

The methods getThreadCount()  and getCurrentThreadCpuTime()  will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the thread count in Windows 10

```
Task manager -> Details -> (right click) Select columns -> (check) Threads
```

[image]